how to increase the number of kernel backups ubuntu 24.04
I need a workaround for screwed up kernels that won't uninstall (see help i've broken two kernels). I have one kernel left that still works with my rhythmbox, If I upgrade my kernel now with the latest version my known good kernel will fall off the list. If the latest kernel still doesn't let rhythmbox play my music files I will unable to recover the old kernel and loose rhythmbox. The sole purpose of this computer is dedicated to being the jukebox of my entertainment center. If I can increase the number of backup kernels I would be able to still have my known good kernel to boot into and use mainline to remove the newly installed non compatible kernel thus retaining my old kernel and my jukebox.
I want to avoid formating the hard drive and recovering with deja dup, some of the data that rhythmbox keeps such as ratings level don't seem to be backed up and disappears. I have over 5000 songs in my library and would have to listen all 5000 to rate them again.
I use the ratings a lot for sorting the music to play.

You can "hold" or "pin" the current kernel packages so they don't get overwritten. https://askubuntu.com/a/1501423/243321 Seems like that's really what you want to do.

hello organic marble. I went to the link, not sure I like what I read. The first paragraph warns not to use this with ubuntu. Later in the article it related to using this on ubuntu 12.0. Can you assure me these approaches will work with ubuntu 24.04, this is how I ended up where I am now???
